# Can you block calls on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone

I have an iPhone 4S running iOS 5 and cannot find (after trying) any app that blocks calls. Is there anything out there that can block calls on the iPhone?

Comment: Blocking a call happens at the carrier level. Any 3rd party app that advertises the ability to block calls does so using hacks that, in effect, quickly answer and then just as quickly hang up on the caller without notifying you (no ringtone). Seamless is open for interpretation. Apple is in the business of making terrific products, I see very little reason they would "be all over this."

Answer (score 2):

I have not found a 3rd party application that does this well. You can obviously block a number via your cell carrier. Since I could not find a good method to block calls with an application I ended up adding the number to be blocked to my contact list and assigned a "silent" ring tone to the contact. Although it will not block a incoming call it will cause the phone to play a silent ringtone when the number in question calls. Not a true block caller solution but at least a potential workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Up until iOS 7, the only solutions for actual call blocking on the iPhone required a jailbreak.

However, it's not that difficult to find an alternative:

1. New Contact into which all unwanted phone numbers are stored
2. Assign a silent ringtone to the new contact.